# real analysis, continuity square root of f(x)

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and $f(x)>0$ for every $x \in R$ Show that the function $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ $g(x)=\sqrt{(f(x)}$
is continuous everywhere.

I've gotten to the point that I have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|/\sqrt{f(x_0)}$
but dunno how to continue

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $$|\sqrt{|f(x) |} -\sqrt{|f(y)| }|\leqslant \sqrt{|f(x) -f(y) |}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$. By continuity of $f$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon \sqrt{f(x_0)}$ for all $x$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Then,

$$|g(x)-g(x_0)| = \left|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(x_0)}\right| \leq \left|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{f(x_0)}}\right|\leq \frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)|}{\sqrt{f(x_0)}}<\epsilon.$$